# MVVM Light DI to share data between VMs?

Tags: design-patterns, mvvm, dependency-injection, mvvm-light

currently I'm using DI to pass data between to VMs, imagine the scenario of a search page and a results page or master/detail.

So in this scenario I should create a VM (with a model or not) that I call "parameters VM" to store my search parameters and I read them in the detail or results VM.

Also I register this parameters VM in the VMLocator and I inject it in the constructors of both VMs.

What I get is that when I search for new data and store the data to search in this parameters VM I successfully get the data as well in the results/detail VM.

So this is a proven pattern using MVVM Light although not very well documented around the web, my question is if this is a good approach in terms of performance and code readability. I would like to know if someone uses another approach without using the Messaging system in MVVM Light.

An annoyance I have with this approach is that I have to encapsulate my parameters inside a VM inheriting ViewModelBase, if I want to inject a normal class I can't propagate the changes to the second VM, I still don't know why I can't do the same with a simple class, I would like to know if anybody knows the reason as well for this. And the reason I create a simple class inside the VM is because in WP and W8 this way I can restore state of the model on deactivation and activation of the application using a factory in the VMLocator.

I would appreciate your comments!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the Messenger is in my experience the best way to communicate between VMs in a decoupled way, I think of IOC, and particulary SimpleIOC in MVVM Light as a way to inject dependencies into the VMs like repositories, services, etc..

```
View ----RelayCommand---> VM

VM ----Messenger----> VM

Repositories ---- SimpleIOC ---> VM
```

Comment: So you think IOC should be used only for injecting vms, services, navigation, application state, etc? and for objects use Messenger?

Comment: Yep, that's how i've using MVVM so far.

Answer (score 1):

We use [EventAggregator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff921122%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx) pattern in our modular WPF application. In this case your viewmodels need no knowlege about each other. Instead they both share an instance of IEventAggregator service which is injected as constructor parameter. Master ViewModel then publish events with special event class (for example when selection changes), and detail ViewModel subscribes on events of that type and, when event occurs, react on them (by showing new details). Using this patter you can set up communication of viewmodels that are in different projects without any tight coupling. Of course both view models share knowlege of event class they can handle.

There are various implementations of this pattern available in internet. Some of them can be installed with NuGet right from your VisualStudio, [Caliburn.Micro.EventAggregator](http://www.mindscapehq.com/blog/index.php/2012/02/01/caliburn-micro-part-4-the-event-aggregator/) for example.

Hope that helps =)

Comment: Thanks, I believe that is a good pattern, I'm not sure but I think is the same pattern used by the Messenger class in MVVM Light, the event aggregator seems a bit more elegant though